# Makefile on python

Tags: python, makefile, executable

I'm trying to write a Makefile for a python script, that will create a `VMTranslator`

executable file, which is supposed to get an input,

meaning this is how it is supposed to be done on shell commands:

```
1)make <==== should make the VMTranslator executable.

2)VMTranslator BasicTest.vm <==== the user is supposed to use it like this.
```

i have tried the following according to what i have found online:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/
    python *$
```

but it is not working.

the files needed to be included are: codeWriter.py , vmTranslator.py , parser.py .

how can this be done?

Comment: If you are familiar with Python and struggling with make, you might have more success with SCons http://www.scons.org/

Comment: its not something i can use, its homework and we have to use it the specified way...

Comment: Do you ever need a Makefile with its dependency-based build optimization? Probably a simple one-shot shell script would satisfy your needs.

Comment: @spacediver no optimization needed. how can it be done with the shell script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python binary is an interpreter. It does not create stand-alone executables.

What you can do is to write a Python script that does what you want, as long as the Python executable is present the script can be made to run transparently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import codeWriter
import vmTranslator
import parser

# Add code here to parse arguments and call into the imported code.
```

Save that as `VMTranslator`, and make the file executable (`chmod +x VMTranslator`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run your script from shell like this `python vmTranslator.py BasicTest.vm`?.. This should work if vmTranslator.py includes what it needs to work. If so, you can write the following into your executable shell script `VMTranslator`:

```
#!/bin/bash
python vmTranslator.py $1
```

Then you should be able to run it like this:

```
./VMTranslator BasicTest.vm
```

You will need `./` in the beginning for the case if your `PATH` variable does not include current directory `.` (which is highly recommended settings these days).

Also, be sure to provide correct shebang line `#!/bin/bash` to locate shell on your system.